# Swift: Combine Dictionaries in an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm looking for an elegant way to combine an array of dictionaries.

```
Input: [[a: foo], [b: bar], [c: baz]]
Output: [a: foo, b: bar, c: baz]
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You could use reduce but you'd have to define a "combine" method that would give you a combined dictionary from 2 individual dictionaries.

So you could do something like this

```
let inputArray = [["a": "foo"], ["b": "bar"], ["c": "baz"], ["c": "bazx"]]
let flat = inputArray.reduce([:]) { $0 + $1 }
```

If you overloaded "+" on Dictionary

```
func + <K, V>(lhs: [K : V], rhs: [K : V]) -> [K : V] {
    var combined = lhs

    for (k, v) in rhs {
        combined[k] = v
    }

    return combined
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in one step? I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of `var output = dict.reduce([:]) { (var combined, current) in
    combined[current[0]] = current[1]
}` But obviously the vars aren't passed as anything subscriptable, any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do that with **Swift 4.2**:

```
let inputArray = [["a": "foo"], ["b": "bar"], ["c": "baz"], ["c": "bazx"]]
let result = inputArray.flatMap { $0 }.reduce([:]) { $0.merging($1) { (current, _) in current } }
```

Output:

```
["b": "bar", "c": "baz", "a": "foo"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a horrible solution...

```
let inputArray = [["a": "foo"], ["b": "bar"], ["c": "baz"]]

let inputArrayFlat = inputArray.reduce([String:String]()) {
    var output = $0
    for (key, value) in $1 { output[key] = value }
    return output
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a `Dictionary` extension:

```
extension Dictionary {
    init<S: SequenceType where Element == S.Generator.Element>(_ s:S) {
        self.init()
        var g = s.generate()
        while let e: Element = g.next() {
            self[e.0] = e.1
        }
    }
}
```

With this extension, you can initialize `Dictionary` with a sequence of `(Key, Value)` pairs. So you can:

```
let input = [["a": "foo"], ["b": "bar"], ["c": "baz"]]

let output = Dictionary(input.reduce([], { $0 + $1 }))
```

Answer (score 2):

Merges an array of dictionaries into a single dictionary, overwriting duplicate existing keys with the new key.

```
extension Array where Element == [String:String] {
    func merged() -> [String:String] {
        reduce(into: [String:String]()) { $0.merge($1) { $1 } }
    }        
}
```

Turns `[[String:String]]` into a single `[String:String]`.

```
let test = [["a":"1", "b":"2"], ["a":"3", "c":"4"]]
assert(test.merged() == ["a":"3", "b":"2", "c":"4"])
```

I'd like a generic version of this that does not rely on `String`, but am having a hard time expressing it to the compiler. Please edit or comment if anyone wants to have a go at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let inputArray = [["a": "foo"], ["b": "bar"], ["c": "baz"]].reduce([], +)
var result:[String:String] = [:]
for item in inputArray {
    result.updateValue(item.1, forKey: item.0)
}
println(result.description)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let inputArray = [["a": "foo"], ["b": "bar"], ["c": "baz"], ["c": "bazx"]]

var flat = [String:String]()
for e in inputArray {
    for (k, v) in e {
        flat[k] = v
    }
}

dump(flat)
```

Comment: While this does work, I was looking for something a bit shorter, stuff like map() or a join function.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think this is possible out of the box with Swift dictionaries at this point in time.

Comment: There are an intriguing array of alternative approaches, but it's worth noting that this is one of the most efficient. Benchmark them and you'll see a remarkable range of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `reduce` twice—once on the outer array, and once on the inner dictionaries as they get processed. If any of the dictionaries have duplicate keys, this version will only keep the last value for that key.

```
func flattenDictionaryList<T, U>(list: [[T: U]]) -> [T: U] {
    return list.reduce([:]) { combined, current in
        reduce(current, combined) { (var innerCombined: [T: U], innerCurrent: (key: T, value: U)) in
            innerCombined[innerCurrent.key] = innerCurrent.value
            return innerCombined
        }
    }
}

let input = [["a": "foo"], ["b": "bar"], ["c": "baz"]]
let output = flattenDictionaryList(input)
```